# Drive is mounted and usable, but missing from Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mount

Currently I have a flash drive plugged into my computer, however no autoplay action is fired and the drive does not show up in My Computer.  However, in Disk Management I see the drive and can use it by manually typing in the mount letter into explorer (E).  Any idea as to why this is happening?

I have two HDDs mounted as C & D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this on my own, apparently my past self hid the E drive from my computer using the "NoDrives" registry key.  Deleted the key, problem solved.  For more information on the NoDrives key, [see here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/).